# Impute mean of single column in dask-ml

Tags: python, machine-learning, dask, dask-ml

Calculating and imputing the mean using dask-ml works fine when changing all the columns that are `np.nan`:

```
imputer = impute.SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
data = [[100, 2], [np.nan, np.nan], [70, 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Weight', 'Age']) 
x3 = imputer.fit_transform(df)
print(x3)

    Weight  Age
 0  100.0   2.0
 1  85.0    4.5
 2  70.0    7.0
```

But what if I need to leave `Age` untouched? Is it possible to specify what columns to impute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify colums by
`df.Weight = imputer.fit_transform(df.Weight)` or by indexing columns `df.loc["Weight"]`

Comment: Can you please provide the full code? I'm getting `Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead`

Comment: It has to have 2D array, I converted code into iloc but you still can use loc by reshaping. `df.iloc[:, 0:1] = imputer.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,0:1])`

Comment: This worked. As an additional comment, it is possible to select any number of columns in `iloc` to calculate the mean, not just one or a range of columns.

Comment: If I understood right, sure it is possible. To select 0th, 1st, and 2nd columns, you can do sth like the following:

`df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 2]]`